# Downcasting instance from external Jar

Tags: java, downcast

```
//Class defined in external jar
class A{
    many methods...
    public getId() {};
}

//I want to extends this class and overwrite single method
class MyA extends A{
private int myId;
public getId() {return myId};
}

void main ()
{
  A a = Factory.getA(); //External class create the instance
  MyA mya = (MyA)a;     //runtime Error!! I want to convert A to myA
}
```

Hi,
I want to extends an instance which I get from external Jar and overwrite a single method getId(). I don't control the creation of the instance so the only solution I got was to pass it to my constructor and init all members manually, example here:

```
class MyA extends A{
private int myId;
public MyA(A a, int myId)
{
    this.myId = myId;
    //init all other methods from a.? to this.?
    this.setXXX(a.getXXX());
    this.setYYY(a.getYYY());
    ....many methods...
}
public getId() {return myId};
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: No, there's no better way. You can't downcast `A` to `MyA` any more than you can cast an `Object` to a `String`. The factory created an `A` and it'll stay an `A` unless you convert it to `MyA` somehow, for example with your constructor.

Comment: You could use reflection to modify the behaviour of A.

Answer (score 0):

MyA mya = (MyA)a;     //runtime Error!! I want to convert A to myA
Is a an `instance of` MyA?? You can not convert if it is not an `instance of` MyA. you get `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than getting all data from `A` in the constructor of `MyA` (and thus reimplementing it completely), create an [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), change the methods you need and in the rest just pass the calls to the original instance of `A`:

```
class MyA extends A{
private A adaptee;
private int myId;

public MyA(A adaptee, int myId)
{
    this.adaptee = adaptee;
    this.myId = myId;
}

// Override the method you need to 
@Override
public getId() {return myId};
...
// Override the rest of the methods so they call the adaptee.
@Override
public X getXXX() {
   return a.getXXX();
}
@Override
public void setXXX(X x) {
   a.setXXX(x);
}
...
}
```

Then, of course, use it as:

```
 A a = new MyA(Factory.getA(), myId);
... a.getId();
```